# How to center text inside button without altering button size in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I want the **text inside the buttons to fit on one line**, but got problem:

[image: problem screenshot]

Comment: it seems you are fix the width or too many padding is there post xml

Comment: reduce the text size

Comment: We need your xml code.

Comment: Text in this size clearly does not fit into a button of this width. If you cannot change the button size, the only other way is to make the text smaller.

Comment: if the width of buttons are set to `wrap_content`  and sill facing the problem try adding `android:singleLine="true"`, otherwise you don't have any options  other than increasing the width of the button or reducing the text size

Answer (score 0):

To do that in your layout, you can use following **three ways**

1. `android:singleLine="true"` in button.
2. **change fontsize**
3. you can **reduce margin**.

check this example :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="first button you must click 1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="first button you must click 2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is your problem s0lved ?@Wandhaal Assan

Answer (score 0):

The only option that you have if you don't want to alter button size as you mentioned in the question is to reduce the padding of the button as much as possible and reduce the size of the text.

You can also use

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

But this will change the size(width) of your button.